# allow 1-9 and dash regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This will allow the user to enter a-z but how to add 0-9 and dash to it? `/^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;`

Comment: Will you allow user to enter [white space] ?

Comment: Have you read a tutorial on how to use regular expressions? As this is quite commonly covered and basic. Also do you mean covering 0-9 or 1-9, the title and context of the question vary.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I just don't know where to put the `-`

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d\s-]*$/
```

1. The dash **at the end** of the character class (`[]`) doesn't need to be escaped, otherwise use `\-`
2. To match digits you can either use `0-9` or simply `\d`, depending on your regex flavor.

---

Regex Explanation:

```
^[a-zA-Z\d\s-]*$

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed) «^»
Match a single character present in the list below «[a-zA-Z\d\s-]*»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive) «a-z»
   A character in the range between “A” and “Z” (case insensitive) «A-Z»
   A “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script) «\d»
   A “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line) «\s»
   The literal character “-” «-»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) (line feed) «$»
```

Comment: `\s` is for what? can I do `\s@` ?

Comment: @HarisZ [`\s`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-white-space) is a single white space character. You can, if you are looking to match `"[white space char]@"` for some reason.

Comment: `\s` Match a “white-space character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)

Comment: can I put the `- ` in the first character after the `[` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `/^[1-9-]*$/`

Here's a Javascript example:

```
var reg = new RegExp("^[1-9-]*$");
var s = '1234-5678';
if (reg.exec(s)) {
    console.log("Match\n");
} else {
    console.log("No match\n");
}
```

Comment: what is `=~`? first time I'm see this

Comment: In Perl it is testing whether the value in the variable `$s` matches the regex.

Comment: I'm not sure why an example in Perl was given, a JavaScript example would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek - good point...it was kind of thoughtless of me.  Thanks!